# Python lxml - using the xml:lang attribute to retrieve an element

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have some xml which has multiple elements with the same name, but each is in a different language, for example:

```
<Title xml:lang="FR" type="main">Les Tudors</Title>
<Title xml:lang="DE" type="main">Die Tudors</Title>
<Title xml:lang="IT" type="main">The Tudors</Title>
```

Normally, I'd retrieve an element using its attributes as follows:

```
titlex = info.find('.//xmlns:Title[@someattribute=attributevalue]', namespaces=nsmap)
```

If I try and do this with [@xml:lang="FR"] (for example), I get the traceback error:

```
  File "D:/Python code/RBM CRID, Title, Genre/CRID, Title, Genre, Age rating, Episode Number, Descriptions V1.py", line 29, in <module>
    titlex = info.find('.//xmlns:Title[@xml:lang=PL]', namespaces=nsmap) 

  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1457, in lxml.etree._Element.find (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:51435)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 282, in find
    it = iterfind(elem, path, namespaces)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 272, in iterfind
    selector = _build_path_iterator(path, namespaces)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 256, in _build_path_iterator
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](_next, token))

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 134, in prepare_predicate
    token = next()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 80, in xpath_tokenizer
    raise SyntaxError("prefix %r not found in prefix map" % prefix) SyntaxError: prefix 'xml' not found in prefix map
```

I'm not surprised by this, but I'd like suggestions on how to get around the issue.

Thanks!

As requested, a cut-down but complete set of code (It works as expected if I remove the [bitsinsquarebrackets]):

```
import lxml
import codecs

file_name = (input('Enter the file name, excluding .xml extension: ') + '.xml')# User inputs file name
print('Parsing ' + file_name)


#----- Sets up import and namespace

from lxml import etree

parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser()


tree = lxml.etree.parse(file_name, parser)                                 # Name of file to test goes here
root = tree.getroot()

nsmap = {'xmlns': 'urn:tva:metadata:2012',
         'mpeg7': 'urn:tva:mpeg7:2008'}

#----- This code writes the output to a file

with codecs.open(file_name+'.log', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:                        # Name the output file
    f.write(u'CRID|Title|Genre|Rating|Short Synopsis|Medium Synopsis|Long Synopsis\n')
    for info in root.xpath('//xmlns:ProgramInformation', namespaces=nsmap):
       titlex = info.find('.//xmlns:Title[xml:lang="PL"]', namespaces=nsmap)             # Retreve the title
       title = titlex.text if titlex != None else 'Missing'             # If there isn't a title, print an alternative word
       f.write(u'{}\n'.format(title))                     # Write all the retrieved values to the same line with bar seperators and a new line
```

Comment: Can you show the exact code that lead to this error? seems like the `nsmap` namespace you are defining does not define `xml` in it.

Comment: Code updated above.  The xml files don't seem to use xml:lang as a namespace (but xml:lang="PL" does appear in the top level in <TVAMain.....>)

Answer (score 3):

**Using `find()`**

The `xml` prefix in `xml:lang` does not need to be declared in an XML document, but if you want to use `xml:lang` in XPath lookups (using `find()` or `findall()`), you have to define a prefix mapping in the Python code.

The `xml` prefix is reserved (as opposed to "normal" namespace prefixes which are arbitrary) and defined to be bound to `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`. See the [Namespaces in XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl) W3C recommendation.

Example:

```
from lxml import etree

# Required mapping when using "find"
nsmap = {"xml": "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}
 
XML = """
<root>
  <Title xml:lang="FR" type="main">Les Tudors</Title>
  <Title xml:lang="DE" type="main">Die Tudors</Title>
  <Title xml:lang="IT" type="main">The Tudors</Title>
</root>"""
 
doc = etree.fromstring(XML)
 
title_FR = doc.find('Title[@xml:lang="FR"]', namespaces=nsmap)
print(title_FR.text)
```

Output:

```
Les Tudors
```

If there is no mapping for the `xml` prefix, you get the "*prefix 'xml' not found in prefix map*" error. If the URI mapped to the `xml` prefix is not `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`, the `find` method in the code snippet above does not return anything.

**Using `xpath()`**

With the `xpath()` method, the prefix:URI mapping is not needed:

```py
title_FR = doc.xpath('Title[@xml:lang="FR"]')[0]
print(title_FR.text)
```

Output:

```
Les Tudors
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful?

Comment: Yes, this answer was extremely helpful. Can you provide any insight into why, if the `xml` namespace is reserved and does not need to be declared, ElementTree does not automagically map it? Is there any case in which mapping the xml namespace by default would be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the `xml` file , you should change the `xml:lang` attribute to `lang` .

Or if you do not have that control , I would suggest adding `xml` in the nsmap, like -

```
nsmap = {'xmlns': 'urn:tva:metadata:2012',
         'mpeg7': 'urn:tva:mpeg7:2008',
         'xml': '<namespace>'}
```