# Extract content from meta-tag in <head> with Xpath using multiple conditions

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, meta-tags

I want to select the xpath of a meta-tag with two conditions. Usually it works like this:

```
//div[@id='..' and @class='...]
```

However, the meta-tag I want to extract looks like this:

```
< meta name="Description" xml:lang="en" content="Some text which I want to extract.">
```

And I tried:

```
extract_with_xpath('//meta[@name="Description" and @xml:lang="en"]/@content')
```

Also:

```
extract_with_xpath('//meta[@name="Description" and (@xml:lang="en")]/@content')
```

Also tried several other options, but none of them work.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: can you provide  more information? like the website you want to scrap ? or the web page with this section ? that'll be very helpful to guide you right.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. E.g. this website: https://painmedicine.org.ua/index.php/pnmdcn/article/view/14. Here you'll find following meta-tags in the <head>-section: `<meta name="DC.Description" xml:lang="en" content="some text">` and also one that has `xml:lang="ru"`. I would like to extract them separately.

Answer (score 1):

You have space in tag `< meta`, so I also did not succeed to extract data from it.
But you can try:

```
import re
from scrapy import Selector

txt = """< meta name="Description" xml:lang="en" content="Some text which I want to extract.">"""
txt_stripped = re.sub(r'<\s(\w+)', r'<\1', txt)
sel = Selector(text=txt_stripped)
print sel.css("meta[name=Description][xml\:lang='en']::attr(content)").get()
```

Comment: The space was a mistake by me. Actually there is no space, but thanks for noticing. Is there really no option to solve that issue by using `extract_with_xpath`? I tried your suggestion with the backslash, but this didn't work for me.

Comment: Nope. I spent some time to hack this, but could not find solution. You can check also this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250641/python-lxml-using-the-xmllang-attribute-to-retrieve-an-element But `css` selector that is in the answer works fine for me. If you're ok to use css instead of xpath, this will help.

Comment: While I am still confused, I appreciate your time to research on this. I also found out that it has to do with xml namespaces and need to read more about it in detail to understand the logic behind it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After Observing you website., meta Tag is actually:

```
<meta name="DC.Description" xml:lang="en" content="some text">
```

To extract the content use the following xpath:

```
d_x = '//meta[@name="DC.Description"]'
```

Moreover there are multiple meta tags under same Selector. `xml:lang` is the attribute that differentiate the content but xpaths or css' does not handle this kind of attribute with delimiter. you got to do this:

```
desc_metas = response.xpath(ds_x)    #Extract only metas with description
filter_desc = []
for d in desc_metas:
    filter_desc.append(d.replace('xml:lang', 'lang'))    #Replacing xml:lang with lang only so that our selector can detect that
```

Now to get the respective language description e.g; 'en'

```
en_desc = None
for d in filter_desc:
   d = Selector(text=d)    #converting back, string to Selector
   if d.xpath('//meta[@lang="en"]/@content'):    #now Applying lang attribute to get the desired content.

        en_desc = d.xpath('//meta[@lang="en"]/@content')
```

Comment: I know that this is the way to extract the Description from the meta-tag. But since there are two meta-tags with `name="DC.Description`, it will extract both: the English (en) and Russian (ru) description (they differ in the 'xml:lang' tag`). But what if I only want to extract the English description or store the English and Russian description separately. That is actually my question.